# Covariance between the first elements of the samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, covariance

There are two non-independent samples $a_1, a_2, ... ,a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, ..., b_n$.

In Python I can calculate with np.cov($\{a_1, ..., a_n\},\{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ ) сovariance between these samples.

But how can I get $cov (a_1, b_1)$? Both samples are generated from some known distribution.

This question is probably not very difficult, but I don't specialize in statistics, so I will be grateful for the help!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you want to calculate the covariance between two single data points, as opposed to two vectors? That would not be a feasible calculation.

Comment: @MartinGeorgHaas  Yes, you understood me correctly. But doesn't the fact that these two elements are randomly generated give us something? And if we will think that these elements are variables from that distribution, how I can get their covariance?

Comment: Think of the covariance formula: $cov (A, B) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - \bar{a})(b_i - \bar{b})$ How would that turn out for only one observation?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship between $a_i$ and $a_j$? Are they drawn from the same distribution with some known dependence? And same question for $b_i$ and $b_j$.

Comment: @Ben $a_i$  drawn from gamma-distribution independently, $b_i$ from beta-distribution and also independently. But $a_j$ and $b_i$ for $i=j$ are non-independent

Comment: @Mikhy Ok, to be sure,  you're saying that $(A,B)$ has a joint distribution such that $A$ has some Gamma and $B$ has some Beta marginal distribution, that $A$ and $B$ are correlated, and that $(a_i, b_i)$ is drawn independently from this distribution for $i=1,\dots,n$?

Comment: @Ben  Actually $a_1, ...., a_n$  drawn from gamma-distribution independently, 
 $b_i = a_i + c_i$,  where $c_1, ..., c_n$  from beta-distribution and independent. But $a_j$ and $b_i$ for $i=j$ are non-independent.

Comment: OK thanks @MikhyPenko I'm trying to understand the between sample dependence. Is each $(a_i, b_i)$ pair iid?

Answer (score 0):

###### Without variance in your sample there is no covariance.

Think of the sample covariance formula:
$$
cov (A, B) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - \bar{a})(b_i - \bar{b})
$$

For only one observation, the observations $a_i$ and $b_i$ would be equal to their sample means $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ and the result would be zero.